# How do I size the Canvas in the ListBox according to the position of the elements?

Tags: wpf, listbox, drag

I have a `ListBox`. `ItemsPanelTemplate` has `Canvas` in this `ListBox`. I am dragging items from ListBox within canvas. (Actually, we can think of the xaml design screen in Visual Studio.) If the position of my element is outside the window, I want the canvas to be resized and scrollable with scroll. But I seem to be making a mistake in the sizing logic. If I give the Canvas a fixed size such as Width=3000, Heidht=3000, there will be no problem in dragging, but if a small screen will be used, scrollBars appear unnecessarily. How can I get `Canvas` to resize automatically?

Also, instead of writing the `MouseLeftButtonDown`, `MouseLeftButtonUp`, `MouseMove` events separately for each added control, how can I add the selected element of the ListBox?

```
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ToolItems}"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
             AllowDrop="True"
             Name="listBox">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type controlsViewModel:TextControlViewModel}">
                <controls:TextControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.Resources>

        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Name="canvas"
                        MinWidth="3000"
                        MinHeight="3000"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left"
                        Value="{Binding Position.X}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"
                        Value="{Binding Position.Y}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

TextControl.xaml Code

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestMaster.Controls.Views.TextControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestMaster.Controls.Views"
         xmlns:controlViewModel="clr-namespace:TestMaster.Controls.ViewModels"
         xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:TestMaster.Converters"
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="450"
         d:DesignWidth="800"
         MouseLeftButtonDown="MouseLeftButtonDown_Event"
         MouseLeftButtonUp="MouseLeftButtonUp_Event"
         MouseMove="MouseMove_Event">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:StyleConverter x:Key="StyleConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid >
    <StackPanel Margin="{Binding Properties.Margin}"
                Canvas.Left="{Binding Position.X}"
                Canvas.Top="{Binding Position.Y}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Properties.Title}"
                   FontSize="{Binding Properties.TitleFontSize}"
                   Visibility="{Binding Properties.Title, Converter={StaticResource NullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpaceVisibilityConverter}}"
                   Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSubtitle2TextBlock}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Properties.Description}"
                   FontSize="{Binding Properties.DescriptionFontSize}"
                   Opacity="0.7"
                   Visibility="{Binding Properties.Description, Converter={StaticResource NullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpaceVisibilityConverter}}"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   MaxWidth="{Binding Properties.DescriptionWidth}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <TextBox ToolTip="{Binding Properties.ParameterName}"
                 Width="{Binding Properties.Width}"
                 Height="{Binding Properties.Height}"
                 FontSize="{Binding Properties.FontSize}"
                 materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.PrefixText="{Binding Properties.PrefixText}"
                 materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.SuffixText="{Binding Properties.SuffixText}"
                 materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="{Binding Properties.Title}"
                 materialDesign:HintAssist.HelperText="{Binding Properties.HelperText}"
                 materialDesign:HintAssist.HelperTextFontSize="{Binding Properties.HelperTextFontSize}"
                 Style="{Binding Properties.StyleName, Converter={StaticResource StyleConverter}}"
                 IsReadOnly="True"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

TextControl.cs

```
    public partial class TextControl : UserControl
{
    private bool isDragging;
    private Point startPoint;
    public TextControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MouseLeftButtonDown_Event(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (sender as UserControl);
        startPoint = e.GetPosition(control.Parent as UIElement);
        isDragging = true;
        control.CaptureMouse();
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
    }

    private void MouseLeftButtonUp_Event(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (sender as UserControl);
        isDragging = false;
        control.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;

    }

    private void MouseMove_Event(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            var control = (sender as UserControl);
            var canvas = (control.Parent as Canvas);
            var currentPosition = e.GetPosition(canvas);

            var deltaX = currentPosition.X - startPoint.X;
            var deltaY = currentPosition.Y - startPoint.Y;

            var viewModel = this.DataContext as TextControlViewModel;
            viewModel.Position = new Point(viewModel.Position.X + deltaX, viewModel.Position.Y + deltaY);

            startPoint = currentPosition;
        }
    }
}
```